# Magento2: 3columns Layout renders 2columns-right

Tags: magento2, column, home-page

I am using magento ver 2.2.2 and installed ultimo theme.I want to create home page in 3 column layout.But when I enable 3 column layout i can not see 3 columns in frontend.Please check attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check `<body>` tag class using view page source?

Comment: This is my body tag :
<body data-container="body" class="cms-home cms-index-index page-layout-3columns">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just doing content? Ultimo uses the Bootstrap Grid. You can create any columns you want for the home page. It is under 6.4 on the user manual.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
```